# The passphrase in gnupg's symmetric vs asymmetric encryption schemes

Tags: gnupg

This question is admittedly artificial.  Its purpose is only to help me understand aspects of `gnupg` that I can't figure out from reading the documentation.

One thing that puzzles me about `gnupg` is that the passphrase plays qualitatively very different roles in asymmetric and symmetric encryption.

In `gnupg`'s asymmetric encryption scheme, the passphrase is used only to protect the private key.  It is not used for encryption and decryption per se; for that one uses the public and private keys, respectively.  These keys, in turn, are generated by `gpg2` itself (i.e. `gpg2 ... --gen-key ...`), using what appear to be pretty high cryptographic standards.  In particulars, in contrast to the passphrase, these keys are not of the user's invention.

The situation is very different `gnupg`'s symmetric encryption scheme, where the (user-invented) passphrase is used to actually carry out the encryption and decryption.  In contrast to the cryptographic-grade keys that one generates with `gpg2 ... --gen-key ...`, and uses for asymmetric encryption/decryption, the passphrase used for symmetric encryption/decryption can be any old silly passphrase, like "mysecret".

As I said, I find this difference really confusing.

My question is: what is the most direct way to have gpg2 generate a passphrase for symmetric encryption that is comparable in cryptographic strength to the keys that one would generate using `gpg2 ... --gen-key ...`?

Here's at least one way to do it: generate a a standard *asymmetric* encryption keypair using `gpg2 ... --gen-key ...`, discard the private key, dump the public key of the pair with `--armor`, and use this as one's passphrase for *symmetric* encryption.

Does gpg2 support a less convoluted approach?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The passphrase you use to encrypt the private key (the private key itself is generated randomly) is used in the exact same way as the passphrase used to directly encrypt files with symmetric encryption. There's no fundamental difference between them.

Comment: @forest: what I mean is that, in asymmetric mode, the passphrase is used *only* to encrypt the private key; subsequent "content" is encrypted using the public key.  In symmetric mode, however, what I just referred to as "subsequent content" is encrypted using the (possibly totally insecure) passphrase.  The role of the passphrase is very different in the two schemes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`gpg` symmetric encryption creates a random symmetric key and encrypts that key using the passphrase along with a random salt.  The random symmetric key is used to encrypt the file or message.

Here's a simple example:

**Create a symmetric encrypted message**

```
gpg --symmetric --armor
Hello there!

-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----

jA0ECQMCMvT60tBO0Hj/0kIBF8YvdNeI61L/GSib25ZU1bkeNLTvkwSMfOFUma9u
YjFN5vKzpv8xclcuUT5huIiDlVyDVwON3tbiflavACeiJg4=
=Nt35
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```

The password is `1234`

**View the message components**

```
gpg --list-packets

gpg: Go ahead and type your message ...
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----

jA0ECQMCMvT60tBO0Hj/0kIBF8YvdNeI61L/GSib25ZU1bkeNLTvkwSMfOFUma9u
YjFN5vKzpv8xclcuUT5huIiDlVyDVwON3tbiflavACeiJg4=
=Nt35
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
gpg: AES256 encrypted data
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
# off=0 ctb=8c tag=3 hlen=2 plen=13
:symkey enc packet: version 4, cipher 9, s2k 3, hash 2
    salt 32F4FAD2D04ED078, count 65011712 (255)
# off=15 ctb=d2 tag=18 hlen=2 plen=66 new-ctb
:encrypted data packet:
    length: 66
    mdc_method: 2
# off=36 ctb=a3 tag=8 hlen=1 plen=0 indeterminate
:compressed packet: algo=1
# off=38 ctb=cb tag=11 hlen=2 plen=19 new-ctb
:literal data packet:
    mode b (62), created 1546881253, name="",
    raw data: 13 bytes
```

As can be seen through basic inspection of the dissected message, the symmetric passphrase is not used directly to encrypt the plain text nor even the random symmetric key.

---

*Additional information addressing OP comments.*

**To decrypt the above message**

`gpg -d`

<--- *copy and paste the message in the terminal and type in `1234` for the passphrase* --->

<--- *to exit, press <kbd>enter</kbd> and then <kbd>ctrl-d</kbd>* --->

Result:

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----

jA0ECQMCMvT60tBO0Hj/0kIBF8YvdNeI61L/GSib25ZU1bkeNLTvkwSMfOFUma9u
YjFN5vKzpv8xclcuUT5huIiDlVyDVwON3tbiflavACeiJg4=
=Nt35
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----gpg: AES256 encrypted data
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
Hello there!
```

**Encrypted Symmetric keys using Passphrase and Salt**

There is no need for `gpg` to keep track of anything.  The message itself includes all the needed items for decryption except the passphrase.  The passphrase may not be very good, meaning having low entropy.  However, that's why salts are used.

Salts are non-secret strings that are appended or pre-pended to user passwords/passphrases or the like in order to increase the entropy of the user generated secret.  This may sound like it doesn't work very well; adding a non-secret component to a secret.  But it does work.

For further reading on salts:

[Wikipedia Salt(cryptography)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography))

Comment: Thank you +1, that was really instructive.  Would you mind adding to your answer the commands to decrypt the message you just encrypted?  One lingering confusion is: if gpg creates a random symmetric key for each message, how can the user later decrypt the results?  Does gpg keep a persistent record of these one-time keys?

Comment: @kjo ... see current edit

Comment: I think I may have misinterpreted the statement "`gpg` symmetric encryption creates a random symmetric key".  I thought you meant that it creates such a random symmetric key *for each message* it encrypts.  In light of what you just wrote, I have to conclude that this can't be the case.  Specifically, I have to conclude that the symmetric key is generated *deterministically* (i.e. *not* randomly) from the passphrase.  Right?

Comment: Each message has its own random symmetric key... furthermore the salt is also random and different for each message.  You can try it yourself.  symmetrically encrypt the same message multiple times with the same passphrase each time... In every case, the resulting PGP encrypted message will be different and each `gpg --list-packets` of each message will show a different salt.  As I wrote above, there is no need keep a persistent record of anything within any local database or the like... Each encrypted message contains all the information to decrypt each message, except for the passphrase.

Comment: Thank you for your patience.  I still don't understand, but I figure that my remaining questions are best put forward in a separate thread: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/201155/on-gpg2s-symmetric-decryption.